# How to do Dynamic allocation of task to Threads in java?

Tags: multithreading

i am trying to do an application,like if there are 10 separate tasks and 4 threads are running.My application has to maintain two queue one for tasks and another for threads.If any task needs to execute it should find which thread is free and assign the task to that thread.i dont know how to produce this.Anyone knows what are the concepts i have to look,please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a thread pool of the kind returned by [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)). Just submit the tasks to the thread pool when you need to, and it will be executed accordingly.

Comment: Beaten to the punch by The Skeet... by four seconds. Curse you, Jon! :)

Answer (score 1):

The [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) does pretty well exactly that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could make your tasks [Runnable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to run them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Executor would be best approach for this problem. BUt u need to keep various things in mind while using the executor and also INs and OUTs of executor as Executor is a service which if used properly can be a blessing and if not it can be a big mistake.

Comment: If you would like to outline / describe some of those "INs" and "OUTs" you mentioned, that would make your answer a lot more helpful.